# Best Practices to Design multi-language web site database

Tags: database-design

Best Practices to design multi-language web site database.

Technologies employed here are ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server.

**EDIT :**

I'm looking for table structure and relationship design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the DB side, use unicode (nvarchar and nchar) for your text.

Have a locale lookup table (containing the locale info you need - i.e. decimal point format), and for each table that has localized data add a foreign key to it.

**Edit:** (following comments)

Best practice *is* to use resource files for localization.

Comment: @Oded : .NET Resources files are pain to maintain, I prefer full database localisation approach, store all localized "resources" in database.

Comment: @Yoann. B you can create your custom database resource provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Comment: don't you mean: (nvarchar and `nchar`)

Comment: @Gregoire : Ok, but how should i design my database tables ? Maybe add a "Culture" column on each tables containing values like "en-US", "fr-FR" ?

Comment: @Yoann - what makes you think that having them on the DB will be any less of a pain to maintain?

Comment: @Oded : since i can maintain them directly by a web interface, like any other data. ResX files are very painful, and requires recompilation etc..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is described in detail at http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwDbResourceProvider/.  This shows you how to create a custom resource provider with Admin UI that stores the data in Sql.